# Buscar imagenes similares

Tags: php, opencv

Estoy por iniciar un proyecto PHP que requiere una búsqueda por medio de imágenes similares que esten en una carpeta especifica.
(el usuario sube una imagen y la aplicacion debe buscar las imagenes que son similares a esta)
He tratado de comprender GOOGLE API VISION pero no encuentro la documentación de esta parte...

Alguna idea de como podría abordar este tema... porque tampoco lo he comprendido bien con open cv

Comment: Bienvenido Enrique podrias editar tu pregunta y mostrar lo que llevas de codigo para entender mejor tu pregunta

Comment: Open CV no tiene API para PHP y la documentación de Google API Vision está en: https://cloud.google.com/docs/